# How To Include angular-ui-route in my project

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to be consistent with how I add libraries to my project that uses Bower and Angular.  I've used bower to install my packages so far by doing things like

```
bower install angular
bower install angular-resource
```

It seems to have created files as follows:

```
/vendor/angular/angular.js
/vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js
```

Now, when I install angular-ui-route I get a different directory structure

```
/vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js
```

I am currently referencing all these from my index.html exactly as they are put down in the directory.  My question is "this seems odd to have some in a "release" directory and others not.  I want to be consistent and I want bower update to automatically update my files when it needs to.  Am I lost or is that what everyone does?

Comment: Fact is not every project is released in the same way, some are `dist` folder, some are root, some haven't been built yet and you need to npm install them first etc.. This is among a thousand other reasons people use a task manager gulp/grunt.  Ex :  Your src diretory structure shouldn't matter once you have uglified everything into 1 file upon deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a npm package (`wiredep`), grunt-plugin(`grunt-wiredep`) which look at all of the bower components you have, then determines the best order to inject your scripts in to your HTML file. It looks for placeholders `<!-- bower:js -->`, `<!-- endbower -->` in your HTML file and replaces them with the bower components' main files.

Since every bower component has a `bower.json` which tells where the main file is present for the component, you will have the correct script file injected into your HTML file. No need to worry when we update any bower package.

It's an important plugin I came across. Its used in Yeoman generation of Angular projects.

For more information on wiredep: https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep

grunt-wiredep: https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep